# DataTables how to fill a column with a hyperlink?

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTables server-side processing and would like to add a hyperlink in the first cell of some of the tables.

I am able to add a column and have the table render correctly, but I can't figure out how to get a hyperlink into the cell.

I don't want this in every table, right now it's just going to be for two of them, but that is subject to change.

I use the same initialization for all of my tables, but all the tables do not have the same columns. There could be anywhere from 3 to 65 columns depending on what table I'm rendering so I can't just add the columns into the initialization. Here is how I'm initializing right now:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function ()
    {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });

    var table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100, 150, -1], [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 'All']],
        "dom": '<"top"Bifpl<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
        "buttons": [{
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Selection',
            buttons: ['selectAll', 'selectNone']
        }, {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: ['export', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Export Current Page',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        page: 'current'
                    }
                },
                customize: function (xlsx)
                {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                }
            },

            {
                text: 'Export All to Excel',
                action: function (e, dt, button, config)
                {
                    dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data)
                    {
                        data.length = -1;
                    }).one('draw', function (e, settings, json, xhr)
                    {
                        var excelButtonConfig = $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5;
                        var addOptions = { exportOptions: { 'columns': ':all'} };

                        $.extend(true, excelButtonConfig, addOptions);
                        excelButtonConfig.action(e, dt, button, excelButtonConfig);
                    }).draw();
                }
            }]
        }
        ],
        "fixedHeader": {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        "select": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "./ServerSide.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
//Added this to the initialization
        columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 0,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta)
            {
                if (type === 'display')
                {
                    data = '<a href="FormToEdit.php?everything=' + encodeURIComponent(row) + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
                return data;
            }
        }],
//It adds the hyperlink to all tables and not just the ones that I want
        initComplete: function ()
        {
            var api = this.api();

            // Apply the search
            api.columns().every(function ()
            {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function ()
                {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value)
                    {
                        that
                          .search(this.value)
                          .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's how I create the tables:

```
<?php
    $hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = '$TableName' order by Id";

    $getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
    $rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $CountHeadings = count($rHeadings);
    $tsqlHeadings = '';
    for ($row = 0; $row < $CountHeadings; $row++)
    {
        $headings[$row] = $rHeadings[$row]["Headings"];
    }
?>
<table id="DataTable" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%; border: 1px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach($headings as $heading)
            {?>
            <th class="cell"><?php echo $heading; ?></th><?php
            }?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach($headings as $heading)
            {?>
            <th class="cell"><?php echo $heading; ?></th><?php
            }?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the initialization script above with what I've added. The problem now is that it adds this hyperlink to all tables and not just to the ones that have the **Edit** column. How would I modify this further to get it only on the table if the first column header is **Edit**?

Comment: see :http://stackoverflow.com/a/41210736/1875256

Comment: @EhsanSajjad will that work if I don't name all of the columns? Also since I use the same initialization for all tables, on the tables that don't have the hyperlink column will this mess them up?

Comment: you can see : https://jsfiddle.net/vdpjh1u5/ and https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have made some edits to my code based on what you provided. It puts a hyperlink in the first column of every table, though. Is there a way to limit it to just the tables that have *Edit* as the header of the first column? Or that don't have *Id* as the first header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to go about this in a different way.

The tables that will be editable will be given a different `ID` and then initialized with the above code. The rest will be initialized without the part that creates the hyperlink in the first column. so now I have this for creating my tables:

```
<table id="<?php if($Edit == 1){echo "DataTableEdit";}elseif($Edit == 0){echo "DataTable";}?>" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%; border: 1px">
```

So that if they have `$Edit` = 1 they will get a different initialization. The new scripts now look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
    {
        className: 'buttons-alert',
        "text": "Export All Test",
        action: function (e, dt, node, config)
        {
            alert('Export All Test');
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#DataTableEdit tfoot th').each(function ()
        {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        });

        var table = $('#DataTableEdit').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100, 150, -1], [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 'All']],
            "dom": '<"top"Bifpl<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
            "buttons": [{
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Selection',
                buttons: ['selectAll', 'selectNone']
            }, {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Export',
                buttons: ['export', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Export Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    },
                    customize: function (xlsx)
                    {
                        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                    }
                },

                {
                    text: 'Export All to Excel',
                    action: function (e, dt, button, config)
                    {
                        dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data)
                        {
                            data.length = -1;
                        }).one('draw', function (e, settings, json, xhr)
                        {
                            var excelButtonConfig = $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5;
                            var addOptions = { exportOptions: { 'columns': ':all'} };

                            $.extend(true, excelButtonConfig, addOptions);
                            excelButtonConfig.action(e, dt, button, excelButtonConfig);
                        }).draw();
                    }
                }]
            }
            ],
            "fixedHeader": {
                header: true,
                footer: true
            },
            "select": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "./ServerSide.php",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta)
                {
                    if (type === 'display')
                    {
                        data = '<a href="FormToEdit.php?everything=\'' + encodeURIComponent(row) + '\'">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }],
            initComplete: function ()
            {
                var api = this.api();

                // Apply the search
                api.columns().every(function ()
                {
                    var that = this;

                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function ()
                    {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value)
                        {
                            that
                              .search(this.value)
                              .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
    {
        className: 'buttons-alert',
        "text": "Export All Test",
        action: function (e, dt, node, config)
        {
            alert('Export All Test');
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function ()
        {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        });

        var table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100, 150, -1], [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 'All']],
            "dom": '<"top"Bifpl<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
            "buttons": [{
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Selection',
                buttons: ['selectAll', 'selectNone']
            }, {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Export',
                buttons: ['export', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Export Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    },
                    customize: function (xlsx)
                    {
                        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                    }
                },

                {
                    text: 'Export All to Excel',
                    action: function (e, dt, button, config)
                    {
                        dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data)
                        {
                            data.length = -1;
                        }).one('draw', function (e, settings, json, xhr)
                        {
                            var excelButtonConfig = $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5;
                            var addOptions = { exportOptions: { 'columns': ':all'} };

                            $.extend(true, excelButtonConfig, addOptions);
                            excelButtonConfig.action(e, dt, button, excelButtonConfig);
                        }).draw();
                    }
                }]
            }
            ],
            "fixedHeader": {
                header: true,
                footer: true
            },
            "select": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "./ServerSide.php",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            initComplete: function ()
            {
                var api = this.api();

                // Apply the search
                api.columns().every(function ()
                {
                    var that = this;

                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function ()
                    {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value)
                        {
                            that
                              .search(this.value)
                              .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is allowing me to have table that are editable and tables that are not. and I can just add the `$Edit` to whatever table needs to be edited.

Comment: To avoid an empty `ID` and for concisenees, I would use this: `id="<?php echo $Edit == 1 ? "DataTableEdit" :  "DataTable"; ?>"`. You can accept your own answer, BTW.

Comment: @GustavoStraube I had forgotten about that notation Thanks. I do know that I can accept my own answer, it is making me wait 6 hours from when i posted though.